# How to adjust screen when keyboard open in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector, on-screen-keyboard

I am working in Windows phone 8. In One of the pages of my app there is a `LongListSelector` and under it there is a `TextBox`. When the `TextBox` get focused then keyboard is opened. As the keyboard is opened then the `LongListSelector` is shifted up by keyboard height. If I maintain the margin of the `LongListSelector` by keyboard's offset then some of the items of `LongListSelector` go under the keyboard.

All I want to do is when keyboard is shown then margin will be updated and the previous focused item of the `LongListSelector` should not go under keyboard. Here I don't want to use `ScrollTo()` function to scroll a specific item of `LongListSelector`.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-Prevent-page-0720d963) of workaround. Though this code is for WP8. You will have to make some changes to make this working for WP8.1 like :

1. Tap in xaml will be replaced by Tapped.
2. `((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();`
    will be replaced by

   Window.Current.Content.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
3. `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {}`will be replaced by

`CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {}`

let me know if you face any issue.